# Object Oriented Tic Tac Toe in Python

Tags: python, oop, typeerror, tic-tac-toe

I'm writing a program for a Python class. It must use OOP to create a Tic Tac Toe game. There are a few requirements that I have completed. The final requirement is that the computer player must be 'smart' - doing things like blocking, playing consecutive spots when it can, and so forth. My professor didn't really give us any instruction on how to do this, so I'm a bit baffled.

Where I'm at right now in the program is attempting to provide a check for whether or not the player is one move away from winning via horizontal row. Here's my code (it's extremely messy and inefficient, I know).

```
from random import randint

class TTT:
    board = [[' ' for row in range(3)] for col in range(3)]
    currentgame = []

    def print(self):
        print("\n-----\n".join(["|".join(row) for row in self.board]))

    def mark(self,pos,mark):
        x,y = pos
        self.board[x][y] = mark

    def win(self,mark):
        if mark == self.board[0][0] == self.board[1][1] == self.board[2][2]:
            return True
        if mark == self.board[2][0] == self.board[1][1] == self.board[0][2]:
            return True
        elif mark == self.board[0][0] == self.board[1][0] == self.board[2][0]:
            return True
        elif mark == self.board[1][0] == self.board[1][1] == self.board[1][2]:
            return True
        elif mark == self.board[0][1] == self.board[1][1] == self.board[2][1]:
            return True
        elif mark == self.board[0][2] == self.board[1][2] == self.board[2][2]:
            return True
        elif mark == self.board[0][0] == self.board[0][1] == self.board[0][2]:
            return True
        elif mark == self.board[2][0] == self.board[2][1] == self.board[2][2]:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def choose(self,mark):
        if self.board == [[' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ']]:
            self.mark((randint(0,2),randint(0,2)),mark)

    def choose(self,mark):
        spotx = randint(0,2)
        spoty = randint(0,2)
        if self.board[spotx][spoty] == ' ':
            self.mark((spotx,spoty),mark)
        else:
            self.choose(mark)


    def choose(self,mark):
        spotx = randint(0,2)
        spoty = randint(0,2)
        if self.rowabouttowin(mark) == (0,0) or (0,1) or (0,2) or (1,0) or (1,1) or (1,2) or (2,0) or (2,1) or (2,2):
            self.mark((self.rowabouttowin(mark)),mark)
        if self.legalspace(spotx,spoty):
            self.mark((spotx,spoty),mark)
        else:
            self.choose(mark)


    def legalspace(self,spotx,spoty):
        if self.board[spotx][spoty] == ' ':
            return True
        else:
            return False


    def rowabouttowin(self,mark):
        for row in range(3):
            if self.board[row] == [mark,mark,'']:
                return (row,2)
            if self.board[row] == [mark,'',mark]:
                return (row,1)
            if self.board[row] == ['',mark,mark]:
                return (row,0)
            else:
                return 4
```

My problem is that I get an error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#194>", line 1, in <module>
    x.choose('x')
  File "/Users/richiehoffman/Documents/Python Programs/Tic Tac Toe.py", line 64, in choose
    self.mark((self.rowabouttowin(mark)),mark)
  File "/Users/richiehoffman/Documents/Python Programs/Tic Tac Toe.py", line 23, in mark
    x,y = pos
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

I'm frankly out of my zone of knowledge here, as the assignment is significantly beyond what the couple of days in class we spent on object oriented Python. I'm sure that I made an error at some point in the choose or the rowabouttowin methods that is outputting an integer instead of some iterable data.

Any help?

Comment: A bit off-topic, but if you want to implement a really clever IA, check out [xkcd tic-tac-toe map](http://xkcd.com/832/). Of course you have sometimes let the IA doing a suboptimal moves in order to be beatable

Answer (score 2):

```
def rowabouttowin(self,mark):
    [...]
    return 4
```

This returns an `int` instead of `(int,int)` as expected in `self.mark()`

By the way, I believe your code would be far more readable if you did not use the same names (such as `mark`) for both variables, methods, and parameters.

Comment: As above regarding naming, you also have 3 functions called choose.